# PHP Facebook FQL: Making queries in the new SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

New to PHP and Graph API.

It seems that in the old API you could create a facebook object and pass in a standard query (select blah in blank where x = y ...) but now I don't see how to do that. All of the examples in the facebook documentation have you using a get_file_contents for graph.facebook.com/?fql etc. I've been trying to use that but it seems inefficient for complex queries.

Help? I'm kinda confused and don't understand some of the facebook documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the PHP SDK you can run fql queries by :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
       'secret' => 'YOUR_API_SECRET',
       'cookie' => true,
));

 $fql = "Your query";

 $response = $facebook->api(array(
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' =>$fql,
 ));

 print_r($response);

I’ve also seen it done this way as well:

$param  =   array(
      'method'    => 'fql.query',
      'access_token' => $cookie['access_token'],
      'query'     => $fql,
      'callback'  => ''
);
$response   =   $facebook->api($param);
print_r($response);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's pretty elegant:

```
$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => $cookie['access_token'],
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);
$response   =   $facebook->api($param);
print_r($response);
```